# How to correctly setup keys with Hadley's secure package

Tags: r

I would like to use Hadley Wickam's `secure` package from GitHub.

The example usage isn't explicit about how to create keys and where to store them and I'm messing something up (possibly more than one thing).

I installed the package

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("s-u/PKI") # needed for bug fixes not currently on CRAN
devtools::install_github("hadley/secure")
```

set up a `vault` folder:

`dir.create("vault")`

Then the next step is to add a user / key:

```
secure::add_user("hackr", local_key())
```

and of course if I literally run that last line as-is it says

> Error: No key matches id_rsa

Because I don't have a key. So, I used PuttyGen to create a public/private RSA key pair.

I saved them to my desktop and tried putting the full path in the command above:

```
secure::add_user("hackr", local_key("C:/Users/hackr/Desktop/r_public_key"))
```

But that didn't work:

> Error: No key matches

Then I tried saving the public key in the vault and doing:

```
secure::add_user("hackr", local_key("r_public_key"))
```

but I got the same error. Next I tried putting the public key in the working directory (one directory higher than the vault) but got the same error.

Finally, I tried copying the keys to `C:\Users\hackr\.ssh` but that also led to the same error.

I suspect I need to save the key somewhere special (in Windows I'm not sure where that would be?) and/or I am using the wrong type of key since PuttyGen is for SSH (?).

Comment: There is a new package on CRAN, `secret`, that makes it much easier to encode your secrets. https://cran.r-project.org/package=secret

Comment: @Andrie thanks I will check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `local_key` is assuming your key is stored in ~/.ssh (which is a reasonable assumption).  By default it assumes that the file is named id_rsa.pub so if you've renamed it then you'll need to pass the name into local_key.

I haven't used this package but always remember those wise words "Hack-R [view the source](https://github.com/hadley/secure/blob/b279c217e4eca33f9eefdf2a5d430367135bd8d5/R/keys.R#L46)"

Comment: Thanks, so that's what I was thinking but I thought I tried that (maybe I am mis-understanding though). Did you see the 2nd to last sentence that I added about 5 minutes ago? Was that the same location you're talking about? Since it's Windows I'm not sure because I know what `~/` means for Linux but not Win. After I put it there I tried `secure::add_user("hackr", local_key())` and `secure::add_user("hackr", local_key("r_public_key))` . I will try renaming it now and see what happens.

Comment: `path.expand("~")` will tell you the full path that corresponds to "~".  It should give the same thing as `Sys.getenv("R_USER")`

Comment: !!! OK thank you very much. That expanded to my Documents folder. Let me try this again in that folder and I will update this thread ASAP. Either way lemme go ahead and upvote this answer.

Comment: I created the folder there and put the files there but it's still saying `Error: No key matches r_public_key` . I also tried renaming it to `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: I guess I'd just suggest taking the code in `local_key` and running through it step by step and examine what is in the output and see if it's what you expect it to be. If not then try to figure out which of your assumptions is wrong.  It's hard to debug your particular issue from my end but you should be able to walk through that code and figure out which part is causing your issue and hopefully correct it. Best of luck.

Comment: OK yea good idea, I will go through the source code. I have a meeting now but I will come back to this in 30 min or so. Thansk @Dason . If I get it to work I will edit your answer and mark it as the solution

Comment: Woohoo I got the error to change to "Error: Multiple users match public key:". I'm gettin' close...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Hadley's `local_key()` function is assuming your key is stored in ~/.ssh which is where the commands below will place it by default, and name it `id_rsa.pub`. If you have a different setup, you can change the defaults, or you could simply follow the steps below.

### Step 1

Go to https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/
Read up. It's useful stuff to know.

It will tell you to do this in the console:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Set a passphrase. Remember it.

Then enter this:
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
Enter your passphrase.

### Step 2

Your `secure::add_user("hackr", local_key())` should work now.